# Can Override an observableCollection property in c#?

Tags: c#, oop, observablecollection

How can I override an ObservableCollection property of a parent ?

I have a base class

```
abstract class Base
{
    public virtual ObservableCollection<AnotherBaseClass> items
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

and a child class

```
class Derived : Base
{
     public override ObservableCollection<AnotherDerivedFromAnotherBaseClass> items
     {
         get { //some stuff }
     }
}
```

If I do it like that compiler will say : Items must be ObservableCollection<**AnotherBaseClass**> to match overriden member **Base**.Items

My **AnotherDerivedFromAnotherBaseClass** class is herited from **AnotherBaseClass** so why I can't do that ?

How can I override this property and keep the constraint of the good item type in the child ?

Comment: you can't do that. you could make `Base` generic.

Comment: So, currently I have a treeview with my Base class binded, and I need to retrieve for each Derived class my items. How can I do that ?

Comment: You can't do this.  An instance of `ObservableCollection<AnotherDerivedFromAnotherBaseClass>` is not assignable to `ObservableCollection<AnotherBaseClass>`.  You would need to make `Base` generic, as Daniel suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My AnotherDerivedFromAnotherBaseClass class is inherited from AnotherBaseClass so why I can't do that ?

Because a `List<Sheep>` isn't a `List<Animal>`. It might seem so if you read from them, but you forgot half their power: inserting. Just imagine it **were**:

```
List<Sheep> sheep = new List<Sheep>();

// this does not work and for a good reason:
List<Animal> animals = sheep; 

// whoopsie... a wolf is an animal, but it should never
// be able to be inserted into a list of sheep like this:
animals.Insert(new Wolf());
```

So **no**, your `ObservableCollection<Derived>` simply **isn't** a `ObservableCollection<Base>` and you cannot use it as a replacement in inheritance/overriding.

---

So what *can* you do?

Well, first, what is wrong with keeping the base class signature? It's still valid. The only problem is that one could insert *another* derived class. Maybe have an `IEnumerable<Base>` instead of a real list?

Or you could have a second property with the first making a copy of it... not exactly elegant, but it works:

```
class Derived : Base
{
     public override ObservableCollection<ItemBase> items
     {
         get { return new ObservableCollection<ItemBase>(SpecificItems); }
     }

     public ObservableCollection<ItemDerived> SpecificItems
     {
         get { //some stuff }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for you answer, I understand now with your example. I will just delete the base property, I will just use the child property when I really know what is it type (or getting it with reflexion).